# Can you align-items from the front of the element? Else what other solution is possible to align these?

Tags: css, react-native, jsx

As seen in the attached image, I have a sign up form.
I put the Password input box and it's attached showPassword icon in a seperate View element so that they could be in a row, whilst the main container is a column.

Is it possible to push the Password input box inline with the other elements?

The best solution I can think of is if you can align-items based off the front of the element, rather than it's center point. However, I don't know if this is possible in CSS.

The other elements are simply centered.

[image: Elements in flexbox column]

CSS code in a StyleSheet

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: 'height',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#cffcff',
},
//main input box style
input:{
    width: 200,
    height: '5%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    borderRadius: 15,
},
//style for Password input box
passInput:{
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    borderRadius: 15,
},
passwordInputContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'row',    
    height: '5%'
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to react-native specific markup and other syntax, but there is a way to do this CSS only:

The reason that the icon is disrupting your alignment is because it is in the flow of the document.  To fix, make the icon `position: absolute` and give the parent `passwordInputContainer` a `position: relative`.  Then use position properties like `top` and `left` to position the icon next to the input.

```css
.form {
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  place-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
}

.passwordInputContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.passwordInputContainer .icon {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="passwordInputContainer">
    <input type="text" />
    <p class="icon">Icon</p>
  </div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this effect through CSS by using `z-index` and `position: relative` to make the icon go inside the input box. Although you might need to adjust the structure of your form.

Here's a sample by Sohail05:
https://codepen.io/Sohail05/pen/yOpeBm

```
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Edit: I didn't see the `react-native` tag. But the idea is there.